# OWL-API has issue with EntitySearcher after property rename

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I've been testing fix #892 for OWLEntityRenamer in v5.1.16:

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/commit/ee817a68cbecf76f3a85da6af8df277c551531e3

While it nicely fixed a problem I was having with renaming properties of anonymous individuals, another issue has come up. It is related to EntitySearcher which I use to get data property values.

When looking for data property values of anonymous individuals, the following code fragments give different results before & after a rename command.

Here is the test code - note that nav axioms copies code from EntitySearcher:

```
        System.out.println("** raw axioms");
        ontology.axioms(AxiomType.DATA_PROPERTY_ASSERTION).forEach(axiom -> System.out.println("axiom: " + axiom));
        System.out.println("** nav axioms");
        ontology.axioms(OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom.class, OWLIndividual.class,
                ind, Navigation.IN_SUB_POSITION).forEach(axiom -> System.out.println("axiom: " + axiom));
        System.out.println("** done test **");
```

Here are the results:

```
** raw axioms
axiom: DataPropertyAssertion(<http://www.example.org/rename-search/diameter> _:5197e008-416e-4403-aae7-c5bed69f3d85 "9in"^^xsd:string)
** nav axioms
axiom: DataPropertyAssertion(<http://www.example.org/rename-search/diameter> _:5197e008-416e-4403-aae7-c5bed69f3d85 "9in"^^xsd:string)
** done test **

Now rename diameter to size.

** raw axioms
axiom: DataPropertyAssertion(<http://www.example.org/rename-search/size> _:5197e008-416e-4403-aae7-c5bed69f3d85 "9in"^^xsd:string)
** nav axioms
** done test **
```

As you can see, after the rename command the technique used by EntitySearcher to lookup axioms comes up empty even when the raw axioms are present.

Does using EntitySearcher provide any significant advantage, or should I stop using it and just access the raw axioms myself?

Comment: shouldn't you just open a Github issue if you think it's a bug?

Comment: EntitySearcher is a convenience for migrating OWLAPI 3 code with fewer changes required, but it uses the same methods on OWLOntology that you could call directly. You can certainly do that to work around bugs while the fix is developed and released.